# Magento 2 Blocks in cakephp 3

Tags: magento2, integrate

I want to incorporate my magento store products, in my cakephp site.
Is this possible? Also is this a secure way? I don't want to risk the security of the site too.

Comment: yes, its possible to integrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary using the magento API

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html

I recommend you take a look at something like this

https://medium.com/@ahazeemi/the-totally-beginners-guide-to-magento-2-rest-api-3a773be2b425

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

But the idea is you are connecting to magento store from cakephp site through magento API and showing product search results.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:
https://sarasotawebpros.com/is-it-possible-to-integrate-cakephp-and-magento/

It is explained very well in anove resource hor to integrate magento with cakephp.

Comment: This is for magento 1

Answer (score 0):

yes , it is possible to do so , you can use magento rest api's for it , here is the reference to the api from the magento 2 documentation 
[List of REST endpoints](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/list.html)

To incorporate it in your cakephp 3 , you can use curl to manage the api requests here is reference for that  from the magento 2 documentation
[Use cURL to run the request](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/gs-curl.html)

you can use postman for testing your the api endpoints and can generate the php curl code from it .

To get a product information for a product with the sku Reebok-01 you would hit the request something like this

http://youdomainname/index.php/rest/V1/products/Reebok-01

Actually you have to do a lot more for it , you also have to authenticate yourself for auth 2.0

Hope the links provided will be helpful for you to get started . If you get stuck message me , i will help :)